# How to fix duplicate account in git credential manager

Tags: git, github, credential-manager, git-credential-manager

git version 2.41.0.windows.2
PowerShell version 7.3.5

When I run `git credential-manager github list`, credential manager shows the same account twice:

```
PS C:\Users\<redacted>\dev\src\cs\<redacted> git credential-manager github list
chrisxfire
chrisxfire
```

This results in the following prompt whenever I push to the repo:
[image]

I can remove the duplicate account by running `git credential-manager github logout chrisxfire`.  However, as soon as I open another repo, the duplicate account shows up again.

Any idea what's causing this or how to fix it permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. There is a fix described in this issue

[https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1325#issuecomment-1631642589](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1325)